# making a JSON from multiple input with angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, firebase

i'm new with ionic ,angular and firebase. this is maybe a ridiculous question :)

i'm working with ionic + firebase to make an app, i want to make a JSON from multiple input. i have an interface like below ( image).

[image]

what should i do to make a JSON from 'Menu' as **key** and 'Price' as **value**.
on the image above is show unexpected result, **the result must be like this**

```
[{"yakiniku":"2000","ramen":"1200"}]
```

---

**View**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="item item-divider">
        Menu
      </div>
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" ng-model="menu_resto[0].menu1" name="menu_resto[]" placeholder="Menu">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" ng-model="menu_resto[1].menu2" name="menu_resto[]" placeholder="Menu">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="item item-divider">
        Price
      </div>
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" ng-model="menu_resto[0].price1" name="menu_resto[]" placeholder="Price">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" ng-model="menu_resto[1].price2" name="menu_resto[]" placeholder="Price">
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  {{menu_resto}}
```

**Controller**

```
resto.controller('DaftarRestoCtrl',function($scope,DB,$firebaseArray){
  $scope.menu_resto = [];
});
```

thank you :)

Comment: in your markup...where is the save button?

Comment: that structure is not a good idea....keep your property names the same...`[{name: "yakiniku", price: 2000},{name: "ramen", price: 1500}]` . It's much easier when you are dealing with repeating items that structure is consistent. Also when you need to search firebase

Comment: on my full code there is save button, but in this question i just want to show the result through the `{{menu_resto}}` if you can see on the bottom of my **View** file.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the first array is available on your controller somewhere and that the edits actually change this array. If that's the case, a simple for each that iterates through that array and builds a string should suffice. I'm not aware of anything you could call to just flatten an array into a JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

This question comes down to nothing more than bare javascript.
Please dont index your data twice. Its enough to call the model variables

```
menu_resto[0].menu
menu_resto[0].price
menu_resto[1].menu
menu_resto[1].price
...
```

Then, all you need to do is, on clicking safe button bind the following function with `ng-click="json = genJSON()"`:

```
$scope.json = {};
$scope.genJSON = function () {
   return $scope.menu_resto.map(function (entry) {
       var newObj = {};
       newObj[entry.menu] = entry.price;
       return newObj;
   })
}
```

Please consider reading a basic book on javascript and some tutorial on angular before asking the next question.

Comment: thank you for your answers and advice, I will learn more about javascript and angularjs :)

Comment: Glad to hear that, didn't meant to be harsh, it's just that I have the impression that the average question quality is decaying more and more and I'd like it if more people would actually be doing their own research before handing stuff over to the community. I hope you haven't been offended by any means.